# No filter registered for [@timestamp]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have a [EFK](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-open-source-log-search-and-visualization) platform and I trying searchs using [the PHP API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

This is one index item:

```json
{"message":"New request to POST /match.","hostname":"gandalf","severity":"crit","host":"app-base","application":"app-api","environment":"PRO","ip":"80.38.71.125","user_agent":"curl","user_id":"561226f2fef3874e058b4568","device_id":"match_abs","operation_id":"5665cbccbae4e","operation":"find_match","key":"match.post","code":"0","value_float1":"1","value_float2":"0","value_float3":"0","value_string1":"-","value_string2":"-","value_string3":"-","@timestamp":"2015-12-07T19:11:24+01:00"}
```

This is my test script:

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$logger = new Logger('name');

$hosts = [
    'localhost:9200', // IP + Port
];

$logger = ClientBuilder::defaultLogger('/tmp/el.log');

$client = ClientBuilder::create() // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
  ->setHosts($hosts)        // Set the hosts
  ->setLogger($logger)      // Set the logger with a default logger
  ->build();

$params = [
  'index' => 'logstash*',
  'size' => 500,
  'type' => 'fluentd',
  'body' => [
    'sort' => [
      '@timestamp' => ['order' => 'asc'],
     ],
     'query' => [
       'filtered' => [
         'filter' => [
           'bool' => [
             'must' => [
               'query' => [
                 'match' => ['environment' => 'PRO']
               ],
                 'range' => [
                   '@timestamp' => [
                     'gte' => 1449442800000,
                     'lte' => 1449529199999
                   ]
                 ]
               ],
             'must_not' => []
           ]
         ],
         'query' => [
           'match' => ['user_id' => '561226f2fef3874e058b4568'],
           'match' => ['key' => 'match.post']
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
];

$response = $client->search($params);

echo $response['hits']['total'] . "\n";
foreach($response['hits']['hits'] as $item) {
  echo $item['_source']['key'] . "\n";
  echo $item['_source']['environment'] . "\n";
  echo "\n";
}
```

After run my script I get this error:

```
Dec  8 10:05:50 11.0.0.174 ::php-cli::PRO::-: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception' with message '{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[G9r0YNWZSEG7-tOgMuDNWQ][logstash-2015.12.07][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.12.07][0]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"@timestamp\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@3ff7f796>]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}},\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"environment\":\"PRO\"}},\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1449442800000,\"lte\":1449529199999}}},\"must_not\":[]}},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"key\":\"match.post\"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.12.07] No filter registered for [@timestamp]]; }{[G9r0YNWZSEG7-tOgMuDNWQ][logstash-2015.12.08][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.12.08][0]: from[-1],size[-1],sort[<custom:\"@timestamp\": org.elasticsearch.i in /root/test/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 644
```

The main thing seems this:

```
No filter registered for [@timestamp]
```

But I have this field in any item.

Besides, this query generated by Kibana 4, works fine.

```json
{
  "size": 500,
  "sort": {
    "@timestamp": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": true,
          "query": "(user_id: 561226f2fef3874e058b4568) and  (key:match.post)"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "environment": {
                    "query": "PRO",
                    "type": "phrase"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1449442800000,
                  "lte": 1449529199999
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "30m",
        "pre_zone": "+01:00",
        "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1449442800000,
          "max": 1449529199999
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "*",
    "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "@timestamp"
  ]
}
```

Whats is wrong?

Thanks a lot to all.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in the query.

'must' clausule content  (inside bool filter) must be an array.

So my php code need to be like this.

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$logger = new Logger('name');

$hosts = [
    'localhost:9200', // IP + Port
];

$logger = ClientBuilder::defaultLogger('/tmp/el.log');

$client = ClientBuilder::create() // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
  ->setHosts($hosts)        // Set the hosts
  ->setLogger($logger)      // Set the logger with a default logger
  ->build();

$params = [
  'index' => 'logstash*',
  'size' => 500,
  'type' => 'fluentd',
  'body' => [
    'sort' => [
      '@timestamp' => ['order' => 'asc'],
     ],
     'query' => [
       'filtered' => [
         'filter' => [
           'bool' => [
             'must' => [
               ['query' => [
                 'match' => ['environment' => 'PRO']
               ]],
               ['range' => [
                   '@timestamp' => [
                     'gte' => 1449442800000,
                     'lte' => 1449529199999
                   ]
               ]],
             'must_not' => []
           ]
         ],
         'query' => [
           'match' => ['user_id' => '561226f2fef3874e058b4568'],
           'match' => ['key' => 'match.post']
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
];

$response = $client->search($params);

echo $response['hits']['total'] . "\n";
foreach($response['hits']['hits'] as $item) {
  echo $item['_source']['key'] . "\n";
  echo $item['_source']['environment'] . "\n";
  echo "\n";
}
```